# How do i extract the first image from a particular URL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am trying to extract the first image from a URL using hypertext-preprocessor. How do i do that?

Comment: Care to post the URL ?

Comment: And where is the code for url ?

Comment: Take a look at the [DOMDocument Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). This allows you for example to get elements by tag name and so on.

Comment: It can be any URL. the code should extract the first image using the entered url. wat kind of commands and how do i use it?

Comment: @user2509932 Dude your question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you could use the [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) class:

```
$url = 'www.yoururltocrawl.com';
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

From here on you should be able to get the rest by yourself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If understand your question correctly... this ll be useful for you...

```
$url = file_get_html('http://www.anysite.com/anypath/');

foreach($url->find('img') as $element) {

    echo $element->src, "\n";

}
```